# Ruby Environment Not working rbenv

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rbenv

I have decided to give rbenv a go instead of rvm. I have installed it with Homebrew which was straight forward. I then added the extra lines to my .bash_profile like so (shims, autocompletion and eval statement).

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/completions/rbenv.bash:$PATH"

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

Then after restating terminal I have tried to run it ie,

```
lee$ rbenv version
system (set by /Users/lee/.rbenv/version)
lee$ rbenv versions
lee$
```

As you can see Im getting no versions and no current version.

Is there something I missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you haven't missed anything. You now need to put some Rubies into `~/.rbenv/versions` for rbenv to see them.

You can also get a [plugin](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) which will download and compile Rubies, and put them in there for you.

Comment: rbenv install --list  was the key :-)